# How to check the result display as seleted in filter by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writting test automation by Selenium Python for the Filter function. I am wondering that how can I check the table display the result as selected value
Example: [Device lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdjkw.png)

As in the image above, I have a table that contains all list of devices. And then I choose the Assigned status. As the result expected to display that: All Assigned device are displayed.

Now I would like to let the computer check all status is Assigned not any other Status displayed. That means the filter successful

I have code like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from Pages.loginPage import LoginPage

class filterByStatus(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/admin/Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        driver = cls.driver
        driver.get("https://admin-helper-f21c1.web.app/login")
        login = LoginPage(driver)
        login.enter_email("admin@gmail.com")
        login.enter_password("123456")
        login.click_login()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_filter_status_02(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sidebar"]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        dropdown = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("device-status"))
        dropdown.select_by_value("ASSIGNED");
        time.sleep(2)
        dropdown.select_by_visible_text(" Discarded ");
        time.sleep(2)
        dropdown.select_by_index(0)
        time.sleep(2)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()
        print("Test filter by Status was completed")
```

My code is **not checking the assus yet** it's just select and user see it display

Anyone can help me with this, please.

Comment: post your code or at minimum data

Comment: @Ade_1 Yes I already updated it

Comment: You can access the status code through the request attribute in driver.request.response.status_code

Comment: @Ade_1 Can you give me an example please, I have just learn about it so I do not understand deeply.

Comment: Apologies, my earlier response wasnt clear. Selenium has now direct way of checking status_codes (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/http_response_codes/) however, you could use requests (e.g) to  s your if condition